# How to prevent accordion from toggling when button in header is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap's accordion class and want to have buttons in the header that can be clicked without toggling the accordion. Here's example HTML:

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="width: 80%">
        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#container1" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <h4 class="panel-title" style="display: inline-block;">
               title
            </h4>
        <div style="float: right; width: 130px; text-align: right;"><span style="color: red;">test</span></div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" style="float: right;" onclick="foo(event);">Button</button>
    </div>
    <div id="container1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            panel content
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried using an `onclick` handler with `e.preventDefault();` to stop the accordion from triggering, but it didn't work:

```
window.foo = function(e) {
    console.log("foo");
    $(".body").append("<br>foo");
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Bye8K/2/)

How can I prevent the accordion from triggering when the button is clicked?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545477/jquery-accordion-header-with-jquery-ui-icon-button-hide-show-hover-click

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want to stop event bubbling, so you use [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation):

```
window.foo = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Bye8K/3/

Comment: Just a note for people activating bootstraps modals with the button (at least in React) you have to stop the propagation in the modals onClick, else clicking the modal will expand/collapse the accordion as well.