# Button in a clickable header

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some collapse tabs that collapse when I click in the header, this is ok, but if I click in the link at the end of each header it shouldn't collapse it, it should run the link action. Is it possible?

http://plnkr.co/edit/aDp8IoV9VQKVrroH2Mk9?p=preview

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion" >
    <div class="accordion-group">
      <div class="accordion-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" href="#" style="padding: 10px;">
        <div class="pull-right"><a href="#">Link 1</a></div>
        Item #1
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class=" collapse in">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
      <div class="accordion-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" href="#" style="padding: 10px;">
        <div class="pull-right"><a href="#">Link 2</a></div>
          Item #2
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class=" collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
      <div class="accordion-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" href="#" style="padding: 10px;">
        <div class="pull-right"><a href="#">Link 3</a></div>
          Item #3
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class=" collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent accordion from toggling when button in header is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469602/how-to-prevent-accordion-from-toggling-when-button-in-header-is-clicked)

Comment: Yep, but it had been answered 9 years ago, cheers for the feedback tho

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to stop the click event on your "a" element from propagating to its parent (the accordion heading) which will trigger the collapse.

This piece of jQuery will do the trick:

```
$('.accordion-heading a').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```