# Preventing accordion with dropdown button from collapsing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, accordion

I have an accordion with bootstrap dropdown button and want to prevent accordion from collapsing, when dropdown button is clicked. I did it by this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469602/how-to-prevent-accordion-from-toggling-when-button-in-header-is-clicked), however there is no dropdown, and in my case it returns:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

My accordion:

```
<div id="protocols-accordion">

  <h6 id="header-<?php echo $pId;?>" class="protocol-header"> 

    <div class="dropdown protocol-buttons" id="protocol-buttons-<?php echo $pId; ?>">

        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle protocol-dropdown" onClick="preventCollapse(event)"
                type="button" id="contact-dropdown-<?php echo $cId; ?>" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="contact-dropdown-<?php echo $pId; ?>">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" onClick="editProtocol(<?php echo $pId; ?>)">Edit...</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" onClick="deleteProtocol(<?php echo $pId; ?>)">Delete...</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

  </h6>

  <div class="content">
      Some content
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
window.preventCollapse = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#protocols-accordion .ui-state-active .protocol-dropdown').trigger('click');
}
```

Whats is causing that error and is there any solution for this?

Comment: You have a `onClick="preventCollapse(event)"`  for the `.protocol-dropdown` so for every click event `preventCollapse`  is called and because you call `.trigger('click')` inside of that you create something like an  _endless loop_. Thats why you get a `Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: I was trying also `onClick="preventCollapse(event)"` for `.dropdown` div but it gives the same result.

Comment: Events bubble up the DOM, so if you trigger `click` on `.protocol-dropdown` is bubbles up to `.dropdown`  calling the `preventCollapse(event)`. So you still have the same situation.

Comment: Well thanks, now I understand what is causing infinite loop, but I still don't get how could I fix it.

Comment: If you try to prevent the collapsing why do you then trigger a new event after you stopped the propagation? Having `onClick="preventCollapse(event)"` for the  `.protocol-dropdown`  and preventing the propagation there without triggering a new one should prevent the collapsing, at least I would guess so. Why do you do `.trigger('click')` at all?

Comment: Because I need to trigger event for "dropdowning" dropdown button. I was aslo trying to trigger `click.bs.dropdown` but still the same result. Collapsing is already prevented, but can't get that drodown menu to pop-up.

Comment: @Incredible did you get the fix for this if yes please let me know