# Bootstrap 5 : Event stopPropagation() or stopImmediatePropagation() is not working in According

Tags: javascript, accordion, bootstrap-5, stoppropagation

I am trying to apply a span tag with some click event inside my according header

but,

I do not want to show or collapse my according.

So I have used stopPropagation() and stopImmediatePropagation() but they both did not work.

Below is the working example which replicates the issue - https://jsfiddle.net/9pL40roz/1/

```
window.foo = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('test')
}
```

I want to achieve something mentioned in the link below

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24469635

Answer (score 2):

you have to apply this steps

1. Add position-relative (Bootstrap class) for all accordion header
2. Add position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle (Bootstrap class) for all options buttons and then handle with z-index (.btn-up)

```css
.btn-up{
    z-index:2000 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header position-relative" id="headingOne">
       <button  type="button" onclick="alert(this.innerText)" class="btn-up btn-sm btn-primary position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle">Options 1</button>
      <button class="accordion-button " type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header position-relative" id="headingTwo">
      <button  type="button" onclick="alert(this.innerText)" class="btn-up btn-sm btn-primary position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle">Options 2</button>
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header position-relative" id="headingThree">
       <button  type="button" onclick="alert(this.innerText)" class="btn-up btn-sm btn-primary position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle">Options 3</button>
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed " type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
        Accordion Item #3
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```